# error checking using bool and radiobuttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, boolean

I'd like to implement some error checking on my program.
If properties have not been selected my program should throw up an error message instructing the user to input the missing information.
I've implemented this for some properties but the final part which deals with radio buttons and bools is causing me trouble.

```
 private void btnAddPatient_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)////Adds Patients using buttone etc to set properties
    {
        string name = txtPatientName.Text,bloodType;
        int x=1;           
         DateTime dob;
        bool bloodA = rbA.IsChecked.Equals(true);
        bool bloodB = rbB.IsChecked.Equals(true);
        bool bloodAB = rbAB.IsChecked.Equals(true);
        bool blood0 = rb0.IsChecked.Equals(true);



        if (dpDOB.SelectedDate == null || txtPatientName.Text == "" || rbA.IsChecked.Equals(false) || rbB.IsChecked.Equals(false) || rbAB.IsChecked.Equals(false) || rb0.IsChecked.Equals(false))
        {

            if (txtPatientName.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter Patient's Name");
            }

            else if (dpDOB.SelectedDate == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a date");
            }


            else if (rbA.IsChecked.Equals(false) || rbB.IsChecked.Equals(false) || rbAB.IsChecked.Equals(false) || rb0.IsChecked.Equals(false))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter patient's blood type");

            }

        }

        else
        {
            if (bloodA)
            {
                bloodType = "A";
            }
            else if (bloodB)
            {
                bloodType = "B";
            }
            else if (bloodAB)
            {
                bloodType = "AB";
            }

            else
            {
                bloodType = "0";
            }


            dob = dpDOB.SelectedDate.Value;

            Patient patient = new Patient(name, bloodType, x, dob);

            MainWindow mainWindow = Owner as MainWindow;

            patients.Add(patient);
            lstPatients.ItemsSource = null;
            lstPatients.ItemsSource = patients;
            // this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What trouble you have exactly?

Comment: Even If I check one of the radiobuttons the code does not move on to the else statement where properties are assign etc.

Comment: Yes. Your code says if one of the radio buttons is NOT checked, go send warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got the values captured in the blood# variables, so you may use one of these approaches:

Using the variables for your if statement:

```
if (!(bloodA || bloodB || bloodAB || blood0))
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter patient's blood type");
```

Using a list (just one more line):

```
List<bool> rbValues = new List<bool>() { bloodA, bloodB, bloodAB, blood0 };
if (!rbValues.Any(b => b))
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter patient's blood type");
```

Or making it reusable within your method, as you use it for other evaluations:

```
var anyBlood = (bloodA || bloodB || bloodAB || blood0)

...
if (dpDOB.SelectedDate == null || txtPatientName.Text == "" || !anyBlood)
...
    if (!anyBlood)
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter patient's blood type");
```

Hope it helps